# Angular Service subscribe not allowed in component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service that's returning some code:

Here is the code for the service and for the component:

Code in service:

```
async readdir() {
    try {
      const ret = await Filesystem.readdir({
        path: '',
        directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents
      });
      return ret;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Unable to read dir', e);
    }
  }
```

Code in Component

```
getdirdata() {
    this.filesystemService.readdir().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

My issue is that it doesn't like subscribe...

I get:

```
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<ReaddirResult[]>'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result type is a Promise, not an Observable to can subscribe on it. For Promises use then() to get the result.

```
getdirdata() {
   this.filesystemService.readdir().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
   });
}
```

[More about Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

you can convert the promise result into an observable using from operator

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
async readdir() {
    try {
      const ret = await Filesystem.readdir({
        path: '',
        directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents
      });
      return from(ret);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Unable to read dir', e);
    }
  }
```

then you can subscribe for the answer, because readdir() result will be an Observable:

```
getdirdata() {
   this.filesystemService.readdir().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
   });
}
```

Comment: Would it be hard to convert it to an Observable?

Comment: No. Anyway, in Angular usually is used Observables, not Promise

Comment: Checked it but it doesn't like the const 'ret' I get: Argument of type 'ReaddirResult' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
  Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'ReaddirResult' but required in type 'Iterable<any>'.ts(2345)

Comment: provide Filesystem.readdir() method. You can convert directly there into an Observable instead of Promise, avoiding using 'from'

Answer (score 0):

`Subscribe` is one of the methods of an Observable, however in your case you're using a promise.

You should be using `.then` to get the resolved data.

```
getdirdata() {
    this.filesystemService.readdir().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

You can even use async await pattern likeso:

```
async getdirdata() {
    const data = await this.filesystemService.readdir();
  }
```

Comment: How can I make it use an Observable instead?

Comment: Show your `FileSystemService` implementation then I can provided you the steps.